# SharePoint 2013 People Picker error message "No exact match was found"

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, people-picker

I have created document library where I have added people and group account column. I have make SharePoint group which some user trying to select they cannot select and they can error message No exact match was found but by system admin user can select it.

What can be the reason for it.

Answer (score 0):

Whether this group is SharePoint group or AD group?

If it’s SharePoint group, does this issue occurred for only SharePoint group or all SharePoint group?

If it’s AD group, you can find the AD group in Active Directory Users and Computers, right click the group and click Properties, check if there is read permission for relevant users in Security tab.

Comment: It is SharePoint Group and it is happening to all SharePoint Group